# ReactJS having issue with checkbox filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a hard time troubleshooting the checkbox filtering issue as I am a beginner in ReactJS . The code that i am using is based on the reference that i found from internet and i changed it based on my requirement. Due to my lack of knowledge, there is one issue that i need help with:

1)The filtering process has some issue, i have two different filter process(filterList & filterList2). When i try to integrate them together in UseEffect, it does not work well as it seem to be overwriting the first filtering process(filterList). filterList will only work if i remove the second filtering process(filterList2).

The result that i am hoping to achieve is that i should be able to display filtered result by checked both filterList and filterList2 checkbox, where the filtering process will involve using searchList as the sample data

Code for creating array

```
 // First List: Learning Direction
    const filterList = [
      {
        learningDirection: "Today"
      },
      {
        learningDirection: "Tomorrow"
      },
      {
        learningDirection: "Leadership and Development"
      }
      ];

      // Second List: Target Audience

      const filterList2 = [
        {
          targetAudience: "Ancillary Staff"
        },
        {
          targetAudience: "Clinical Staff"
        },
        {
          targetAudience: "Educators"
        },
        {
          targetAudience: "Management Staff"
        },
        {
          targetAudience: "Researchers"
        },
 
      ];

 // Data
      const searchLists = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Course 1",
          learningDirection: "Today",
          targetAudience: "Ancillary Staff",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Course 2",
          learningDirection: "Tomorrow",
          targetAudience: "Researchers",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Course 3",
          learningDirection: "Today",
          targetAudience: "Management Staff",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Course 4",
          learningDirection: "Leadership and Development",
          targetAudience: "Educators",
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Course 5",
          learningDirection: "Leadership and Development",
          targetAudience: "Clinical Staff",
        }
      ];
```

Code for creating filtering process

```
      const [learningDirection, setlearningDirection] = useState([]);
      const [targetAudience, settargetAudience] = useState([]);
      const [filteredlist, setFilteredlist] = useState([]);
        
      const handleChange1 = (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
          setlearningDirection([...learningDirection, e.target.value]);
        } else {
          setlearningDirection(learningDirection.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
          }

          if (e.target.checked) {
            settargetAudience([...targetAudience, e.target.value]);
          } else {
            settargetAudience(targetAudience.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
            } 
        };
        
        useEffect(() => {
          if (learningDirection.length === 0) {
            setFilteredlist(searchLists);
          } else {
            setFilteredlist(
              searchLists.filter((filterList) =>
                learningDirection.some((category) => [filterList.learningDirection].flat().includes(category))
              )
            );
          }


          if (targetAudience.length === 0) {
            setFilteredlist(searchLists);
          } else {
            setFilteredlist(
              searchLists.filter((filterList2) =>
                targetAudience.some((category) => [filterList2.targetAudience].flat().includes(category))
              )
            );
          }
        }, [learningDirection,targetAudience]);
```

Code for displaying checkbox

```
                    <div className="searchContainer">
                      <form>


                        <b style={{ textAlign: "center", color:"white" }}> 
                        Learning Direction 
                        </b>
                        <br/>


                        <div style={{ textAlign: "left",color:"white" }}>
                          <hr/>
                            <FormControl>
                              <FormGroup>
                                {filterList.map((filterList) => (
                                  <FormControlLabel
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  control={<Checkbox onChange={handleChange1} />}
                                  label={filterList.learningDirection}
                                  value={filterList.learningDirection}
                                  />
                                ))}
                              </FormGroup>
                            </FormControl>


                          <hr/>
                            <FormControl>
                              <FormGroup>
                                {filterList2.map((filterList2) => (
                                  <FormControlLabel
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  control={<Checkbox onChange={handleChange1} />}
                                  label={filterList2.targetAudience}
                                  value={filterList2.targetAudience}
                                  />
                                ))}
                              </FormGroup>
                            </FormControl>


                        
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
```

Code for displaying filteredlist data

```
           <Fragment>
            
              {filteredlist.map((item, index) => (
              
              <Card style={{ background: "lightgreen", marginBottom: "5px" }}>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" noWrap>
                  Course Name: {item.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" noWrap>
                  Course Type: {item.learningDirection}
                </Typography>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" noWrap>
                  Audience: {item.targetAudience}
                </Typography>
              </Card>

              ))}
            
            </Fragment>
```

Comment: This would probably be better as 2 separate questions.

Comment: @CascadiaJS Hello, thank you for your response, i would like to apologize in advance as this is my first time posting a question in stackoverflow. I have already edited the post in such a way that there is only one existing question for now

Comment: I guess this problem is useEffect watching array in deps. so, It is not changed filtering you want.

Comment: @Stardust123 Could you setup some example code on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: @MichaelHoobler sure, here is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-cache-q0t4y?file=/src/components/catalogueLIstCourse.js

Comment: @shun10114 i include the link to the codesandbox incase you want to look further into the issue and thank you for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had a little bit of trouble getting the codesabox to work. I still found the issue though. There's two big issues. ORIGINAL:

```
const handleChange1 = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    setlearningDirection([...learningDirection, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    setlearningDirection(
      learningDirection.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value)
    );
  }

  if (e.target.checked) {
    settargetAudience([...targetAudience, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    settargetAudience(targetAudience.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
  }
};
```

You shouldn't have this all in one function. With the way this works now, each checked input is getting assigned to BOTH filters (which only break the first filter because of the `useEffect`). A good rule of thumb to follow is to have each `setState` tied to one function (sometimes that unavoidable, but that's what I would do here).  Here's what I mean. SOLUTION:

```
const handleLearningDirectionChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    setlearningDirection([...learningDirection, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    setlearningDirection(
      learningDirection.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value)
    );
  }
};

const handleTargetAudienceChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    settargetAudience([...targetAudience, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    settargetAudience(targetAudience.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
  }
};
// TODO: Change the onChange inside the forms
```

You also have a 2nd problem inside the useEffect. ORIGINAL:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (learningDirection.length === 0) {
    setFilteredlist(searchLists);
  } else {
    setFilteredlist(
      searchLists.filter((filterList) =>
        learningDirection.some((category) =>
          [filterList.learningDirection].flat().includes(category)
        )
      )
    );
  }

  if (targetAudience.length === 0) {
    setFilteredlist(searchLists);
  } else {
    setFilteredlist(
      searchLists.filter((filterList2) =>
        targetAudience.some((category) =>
          [filterList2.targetAudience].flat().includes(category)
        )
      )
    );
  }
}, [learningDirection, targetAudience]);
```

The 2nd `setFilteredlist()` is just going to overrite the first. So the `learningDirection` filter isn't doing anything. This fix is a little more messy, but it does work. SOLUTION:
(EDIT: initialize set with searchLists, and change filters to look for deletions. Also removed if unnecessary if statements)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const set = new Set([...searchLists]);

    learningDirection.forEach((direction) => {
      searchLists.forEach((item) => {
        // Change this to "===" if you want the opposite result
        if (item.learningDirection !== direction) {
          set.delete(item);
        }
      });
    });

    targetAudience.forEach((audience) => {
      searchLists.forEach((item) => {
        // Change this to "===" if you want the opposite result
        if (item.targetAudience !== audience) {
          set.delete(item);
        }
      });
    });

    setFilteredlist([...set]);
  }, [learningDirection, targetAudience]);
```

We're using a `Set` to avoid duplicate values, looping over the checked values, then looping over the `searchList` to get the results. That happens first THEN we assign the results to the state (using the ... operator so we turn the set into an array).

Overall, part of me wants to completely refactor this component. The solutions here should get you up and running to move forward, but I feel as though there's a lot of unnecessary complexity in how you're handling things. I'd have to spend a lot more time trying to understand what's going on to be really sure of that and provide a better alternative though.

Edit2: Providing two alternatives

My guess is that this is how you want the filters:

```
    // Have all the results
    const set = new Set([...searchLists]);

    // Remove unselected check boxes (if any are selected)
    if (learningDirection.length) {
      searchLists.forEach((item) => {
        if (!learningDirection.includes(item.learningDirection)) {
          set.delete(item);
        }
      });
    }

    // Remove more unselected check boxes (if any are selected)
    if (targetAudience.length) {
      searchLists.forEach((item) => {
        if (!targetAudience.includes(item.targetAudience)) {
          set.delete(item);
        }
      });
    }

    setFilteredlist([...set]);
```

Or maybe this?

```
// Start empty if there's any selected checkboxes
const set =
   learningDirection.length > 0 || targetAudience.length > 0
     ? new Set()
     : new Set([...searchLists]);

// Add to empty set if any checkboxes are selected
if (learningDirection.length) {
  searchLists.forEach((item) => {
    if (learningDirection.includes(item.learningDirection)) {
      set.add(item);
    }
  });
}

// Add more if any checkboxes are selected
if (targetAudience.length) {
  searchLists.forEach((item) => {
    if (targetAudience.includes(item.targetAudience)) {
      set.add(item);
    }
  });
}

setFilteredlist([...set]);
```

Comment: I have tried the method that you suggested to me, the filtering process is great and working but there's abit of issue with the display. The idea is that before filtering process occur, the filteredList should display all the default value from SearchList in the beginning(all the checkboxes are in unchecked state). When we checked, the value in the filteredList will change and display accordingly to what we choose to filter. So that the users will be able to see all the courses displayed before deciding to filter further

Comment: @Stardust123 I edited the `useEffect` solution. That should provide the results you're looking for. If not, you can change the `!==` to flip the results. :)

Comment: I tried it out, but the result work slightly different from what i am looking for. Allow me to rephrase. So when the user enter the page, they will see all the default value. If they checked learning for today & learning for tomorrow, courses's value(learningDirection) that matches these two checkbox will be filter and displayed. Another example would be if they checked all learning direction checkboxes, all courses would be display because they matches will all the checkbox value(learning for today/tomorrow/leadership and development).  Likewise the same concept for the target audience

Comment: So you can assume that it's like the first draft of UseEffect u shown me, but with default value displayed in the beginning and will changed accordingly when we checked multiple checkboxes as long as the value matches between the searchlist and filterList & filterList1

Comment: @Stardust123 Sorry that last one didn't work as intended. I added two more solutions and one of those should be what you're looking for. If they're not exactly correct, one of those should be close and you should be able to slightly adjust it to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your help and guidance! the second alternative work the most closest to what i need. I will take a further look into both alternative you provided to further adjust it . Truly appreciate it alot! =D